# os.rename() gives permisson denied when python script launched from jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins

I am getting the following error when I launched my build script from   jenkins

os.rename(str1,str)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

I am able to rename the file manually.I have rwx permissions on that file.But I could not do the same thing when python script launched from jenkins.Any ideas ?

Comment: Make sure  that Jenkins runs with the same user you used to rename the file, or that the Jenkins user has appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using relative path names. In that case it will default to the current working directory, which works when you run it manually, but may fail when Jenkins runs your code using a different working directory. The solution is to make sure that both the `src` and `dst` args to `os.rename()` are absolute paths, or alternatively to `chdir()` to the correct directory first.

Comment: I am using absolute paths only.But this was happening after jenkins was configured to ldap authentication